# LocalDB import and export options not working

Tags: sql, export-to-excel, localdb, import-from-excel

I've created an SqlLocalDB by using the command prompt, and somehow I cannot seem to import or export data into my databases. On any organisational database I don't have this problem, but my LocalDB won't let me do so.

Is there somehow I can fix this issue, since it somehow only targets my LocalDB?

Comment: Please add details about the issue.

Comment: @Christian where I should be able to Import or Export data, when right-clicking on the database, it is grey. If I right click on a database, which is not located in my LocalDB, I can easily import/export.

Comment: why don't you use full sql express then? I need to test it.

Comment: Maybe one of those answers will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126726/how-do-i-copy-sql-server-2012-database-to-localdb-instance, the suggestion is to use the command I posted in my answer below using sqlcmd connected to your localdb instance, another suggestion is not to use WITH MOVE and use the original db path names. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know much about your localdb instance, e.g. creation, rights, where you see the grey restore option, etc. but

the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-2017) show two commands:

`SqlLocalDB.exe create "DEPARTMENT" 12.0 -s`

And then for a 'shared instance' using Adminstrator priveledges

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "DeptLocalDB"  
SqlLocalDB.exe share "DeptLocalDB" "DeptSharedLocalDB"  
SqlLocalDB.exe start "DeptLocalDB"  
SqlLocalDB.exe info "DeptLocalDB"  
REM The previous statement outputs the Instance pipe name for the next step  
sqlcmd -S np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#<use your pipe name>\tsql\query  
CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'Passw0rd!!@52';   
GO  
CREATE USER NewLogin;  
GO  
EXIT
```

Then you can enter the instance using

`sqlcmd -S (localdb)\.\DeptSharedLocalDB -U NewLogin -P Passw0rd!!@52`

I am still unsure what you are trying and how you have done things on your side, 
but I feel you should try to run a shared instance but you still have the "current user" issue then. I fear your greyed out button issue is also a problem related to user rights, although I am not 100% sure.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915521/how-to-share-sql-localdb-with-other-users-on-same-machine) also switched to SQL Express after some difficulties.

Usually you import databases like this:

To find the names needed to import a DB you can run

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'D:\tmp\db.bak'
```

Then restore the DB using

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbnameofyourchoice
FROM DISK = 'D:\tmp\db.bak'
WITH MOVE 'name_of_data_file' TO 
   'C:\...\db.mdf',
MOVE 'name_of_log' TO 
    'C:\...\db.ldf',
REPLACE;
```

Comment: Any progress on that? Here's another interesting article http://www.alteridem.net/2016/03/24/restore-a-sql-server-backup-to-localdb/ showing the restore command / query to import a backup.